# How to make index unusable and then rebuilt in index

Tags: oracle

I have one function that insert thousands of records into table I want to unusable index at that time and then I am processing on that data data so I want to rebuilt that index again.

Is it possible in Oracle?

Comment: i wouldn't bother.  Just leave the index alone and do your inserts

Comment: "Thousands of records" isn't really that much. What are you trying to achieve by temporarily disabling the index? Performance improvments? Something else?

Answer (score 6):

```
alter index idx_name unusable;

alter index idx_name rebuild;
```

but it is possible that you'll need:

```
drop index idx_name

create [unique] index idx_name ...
```

Comment: So what are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but why you need to make index unusable?

In oracle express 11g edition you don't have option of disable index. So the only way is:

```
alter index indexname unusable;
alter index indexname rebuild;
```

In other editions (probably Enterprise) you can replace unusable with 'disable'.