# Purging Oracle Database Records

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration, purge

Consider this table:

```
Table: ORDER [Columns: ID (PK), Order_Num, etc...]
Child Tables: ORDER_ITEMS, ORDER_TRANSACTIONS, ORDER_PAYMENTS, ORDER_TRANSPORT, and many more etc.
```

All the Child Tables have Foreign Keys pointing to ORDER Table Primary Key. And there is huge amount of data.

Now, I have to Purge some Orders. Although I delete records in correct Order i.e Child Table first and then Order Table - It Takes a Very Very Huge time(15 minutes) for this particular Query to run (for a single Order ID):

```
DELETE FROM ORDER WHERE ID='whatever'
```

The DBA Says this is probably because of Child Table dependecies - (FK check), and the child tables contains huge records themselves- hence the time taken (even though all dependencies will be ultimately satisfied - as child records were deleted explicitly upfront).

What are my options:

1. Can I disable FK relationships in Child Tables before executing DELETE on main ORDER Table? How can I easily do this.
2. Any other way to tell Oracle to not check for dependencies?
   Or any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because you have [unindexed foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327190/oracle-delete-query-taking-too-much-time).

You have deleted the children first, but some other transactions may have inserted data in the mean time, so Oracle has to check again when you delete from a parent table.

If a foreign key is not paired with an index, Oracle has to get a lock on the whole child table to make sure that no other concurrent uncommited transaction has inserted a potentially orphan child.

This lock can take a lot of time to acquire, even on small busy tables.

[Adding indexes](http://tkyte.blogspot.fr/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteunindex.html) solves this problem.

Comment: Thanks - this appears to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

[How to make index unusable and then rebuilt in index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534114/how-to-make-index-unusable-and-then-rebuilt-in-index)

This link should help you as far as I know making indexes unusable, stops oracle to check constraints. So it may help you. Make your indexes unusable, delete records, then rebuilt indexes.